# Cors issues using Oauth in Nodejs/Angular local app

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth, cors

My settings are the following :

- Frontend in Angular: http://localhost:4200
- backend in nodejs : localhost:3000

I configured OAuth applications (github, google...) with the backend url (auhorized and callback url)

Then I set up oAuth using passport in nodejs. The frontend only sends http request to the backend when the login button is clicked; the frontend does not communicate with the OAuth provider(is that right ?)

I get the following cors issue:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oshop.com%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&client_id=932090050496-dntdn7u1rg5r9nrm9maqeg1nhm2bc7hs.apps.googleusercontent.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have set up all cors needed headers in my nodejs server but still have the same issue.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, withCredentials");

  next();
});
```

Any clues?
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package and add the following code

`app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true
}));`

Comment: Thank you, this is the same as the middleware I added

Answer (score -1):

It is a browser redirect so you could redirect to local host:3000 (node) and then do either an ajax call to exchange the response code or do the same in node. If you provide some more information on the issue that you are facing, I might be able to help?

Comment: I don't get it: the app should be automatically redirected after login. But my problem is I don't get the login screen yet

Comment: Just so that I understand this correctly, Your Flow is this
1.Click Authenticate Button -> 2.Google Authenticate page -> 3. Redirect page (with code) -> 4. Access Token (exchange code for token), and you are stuck with the 1 -> 2, right?

Comment: exactly, I don't reach authentication page

Comment: Have you given him a button on the page, and is there a place I can have a look at what is happening?